# jaxl/xmpp continuous callback

Tags: php

jaxl library has callbacks to different user defined functions

```
function getId($payload, $jaxl) {           <--------- some function
return $payload;
}

$echobot = new main();
$jaxl->addPlugin('jaxl_post_auth', array($echobot, 'poAu')); <--- callback to a function
```

is it possibe to have a callback that is called continuously after a fixed interval

say

```
$jaxl->addPlugin('jaxl_cont_func', array($echobot, 'callAfterEverySecond'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bit late but if you still care JAXLCron functionality must be used here.... check this for an example: http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2010/01/get-lyrics-for-any-song-using-xmpp-and-php-right-into-your-im-add-lyricsflygtalkbots-com/ , also do checkout v3.x branch which is better/cleaner than v2.x

Comment: ummmm, thanks the post doesn't contain what i want though,
also what i really wanted was a way to make the whole program asynchronous or multithreaded (currently not supported in php i guess) here continuous callback is a way to check for the input and spawn a thread or defer the call for the operation to be handled later. From what i read the post you described calls a function on input received. I have switched to twisted in the meanwhile :)

Comment: Nice you have moved to twisted. However probably you haven't checked Jaxl v3.x - https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/ - It's a rewritten branch which says "event-driven, non-blocking i/o based daemon writing library for custom TCP/IP client and servers implementation in PHP" - basically very much what you must be enjoying with twisted... i have no benchmarks to compare but current v3.x version should be many fold faster than v2.x due to it's async/event based approach